# How can I show children in the taxonomy teaser views of parent/grandparent terms?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Lets assume we have a Taxonomy called Region

Asia - Thailand - Bangkok

If a post is tagged with Bangkok, would it show up in the teaser view on following pages:

/region/
/region/asia/
/region/asia/thailand

or would it only show here?

/region/asia/thailand/bangkok

If later is the case, what's the best way to show it in parent terms teaser views?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding taxonomy as a hierarchical structure like

- Term 1

  - Term 1-1
  - Term 1-2
  - Term 1-3
- Term 2

  - Term 2-1

Then you can get the display using either

1. [Taxonomy Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails)

And css as you wish.

Good Luck.

Comment: Taxonomy Treemenu is unmaintained and should not be considered except as a last resort. http://drupal.org/node/874060